# Llave foránea como null

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

al agregar un registro a otra tabla, la llave foránea me la marca como null, si alguien me pidiera decir a que se debe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde agrego el registro a la tabla agenda, es un boton.

```
 try {

        con = getConection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO agenda, (fecha,estado) VALUES(?,?) ");

        ps.setString(1, txtFecha.getText());
        ps.setString(2, txtEstado.getText());

        int res = ps.executeUpdate();

        if(res > 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dato Guardado");
        Object[] fila = new Object[2];
        fila[0] = txtFecha.getText();
        fila[1] = txtEstado.getText();

        modelo.addRow(fila);
            limpiarCajas();
        } else {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Guardar Dato");
             limpiarCajas();
        }

        con.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: pudieras agregar por favor el código SQL que usas para insertar en la tabla `paciente`?, pues solo nos muestras la inserción en la tabla `agenda`

Comment: Ademas del código cuando inserta expediente que es al final la parte donde se encuera el problema.

Comment: Además de lo que ya han comentado arriba, tienes el diseño de la tabla expediente deficiente - no deberías permitir que se insertase NULL.